# Term for a tech geek who is also a Neo-Luddite

Tags: terminology

*Neo-Luddite* is used to describe those who are considered to be anti-technology, or those who dislike or have a difficult time understanding and using modern science and technology.

Now, I am a passionate geek, who uses technology and enjoys using it. Writing code, using softwares, tweaking my gadgets — all of this excites me and gives me happiness.

However, often I am quite afraid of the future. I often ponder as to how technology eliminated the need of *human muscles* in the previous centuries, and how in this century pretty soon *human brains* are going to be weeded out soon. But, I do not actively protest against it. I use it actively, even teach people around me. But, consciously, I know that this world is going into a deep state of shit where humans are going to be completely useless.

So, what would one call me? Can I call myself *neo-luddite*? Or is there any other term?

Comment: You can call yourself whatever you want to -- no one's going to be filing a libel suit against you.  And terms like "neo-luddite" have no "hard" definition, so no one can really claim that you're being inaccurate.

Comment: @HotLicks Yeah, I suppose these terms don't have precise definitions. But still, neo-luddites give a feel of the 18th centuries' luddites destroying factories (so, a new-luddite "feels" to be destroying data servers and all). Just saying.

Comment: Are you trying to give Luddites a bad name?  I wear the label with pride.

Comment: Haha, I'm pretty sure I'm gonna wear it too :) Anyways, I am just asking if the invocation of "mild violence" is true. Does this word invoke that kind of image in general public's mind?

Comment: I don't think the modern conception of "Luddite" includes a propensity to violence.  In fact, something the opposite -- more a tendency to stubbornly yet passively resist, eg, using a smart phone.

Comment: I am a little confused.  I've got a definite recollection of having read snippets about a Luddite movement in the US, back maybe 1830 or so, which was closer to a religious movement and similar in non-theological ways to the Amish (who eschew many trappings of modernity).  I'm thinking many in the US may refer to that movement when considering the meaning of "Luddite".  (But, alas, I can find no mention of the movement.)

Answer (score 3):

The [Wikipedia article on Neo-luddism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo-Luddism) seems to confirm that "neo-luddite" is appropriate. But, this term is not very usual.

You are also a **technosceptic**.

> Definition : A person who will highlight all the potential negative
>   effects of a technological development. Unlike the technophobe, the
>   technosceptic is not against technology per se, but wants to see
>   evidence of how it will bring about advantages.

Comment: Thanks for the `technosceptic` term. I was unaware of it. It appears to be quite appropriate :)